# React Firebase problem: which is the most efficient way to save a variable?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm coding a react app and I need to save a the value of a variable on Firebase.
It is a variable that increases every time the user clicks a button and after a certain number a part of the code is activated. So I need to save its value somehow.

The point is, I don't think it's not worth creating a collection just for a variable.
So I was wondering if there is a more efficient way, like LocalStorage for example, but its problem is that it only accepts the String type and I'm using the Int type.

Maybe there is some other way I haven't thought of.

What do you think could be the solution?

Comment: The question is a bit vague as we don't know your use case. Does this variable need to be available on different devices? Does it need to persist even if the user erases their device and reinstalls the app? Clarifying the question may lead to a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to save a variable, you could just use localstorage. Yes it keeps it as a string, but you can easily typecast it to your liking.

Converting string to integer

```js
parseInt(value);
```

Converting integer to string (you don’t have to)

```js
var num = 15;
var n = num.toString()
```

Comment: How can I convert a int var to a string one and viceversa?